# Calling a function / database update using Ajax via Jquery

Tags: asp.net, jquery, asp.net-ajax, webmethod

Im creating a simple "Was this useful?" form with  Yes and No objects- Using ASP.net webforms.

I need the submission to be done via ajax using jquery, to prevent a user from voting multiple times on the same page.. currently i have two methods Like_Click and Dislike_click in the C# code behind the page in question.

Can anyone give me some pointers on or a link to any suitable walkthroughs for simple ajax via jquery (I'm new to ajax!)

Ive looked at using the [WebMethod] identifier on each of the methods but do not really understand this method fully.

thanks

Comment: Doing it "via ajax using jquery" will not "prevent a user from voting multiple times on the same page". They could manually trigger the JS that sends the ajax request or hit the URL directly. You should validate that they have not voted before server-side.

Comment: what im attempting to do is use ajax to prevent the page resubmitting on refresh, whilst disabling the objects onclick event when the JS is triggered.

Answer (score 0):

You are probably looking for jQuery's [post function](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/). Check out the examples. You'll want to do something along the lines of:

```
$('.myForm').submit(function(){ //define a handler for the submit event of the form
    $.post($(this).attr('action'), {useful: true}); //send data via ajax
    return false; //prevents the form from submitting via a normal web request
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like below

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        $('#btnSubmit').click(function () {
            var like = $('#Like').val();
            var dislike = $('#Dislike').val();
            if (name != '' && email != '') {
                $.ajax
                    ({
                        type: 'POST',
                        url: 'Home.aspx/UpdateDB',     //UpdateDB is declared as WebMethod 
                        async: false,
                        data: "{'like':'" + like + "','dislike':'" + dislike + "'}",
                        contentType: 'application/json; charset =utf-8',
                        success: function (data) {
                            var obj = data.d;
                            if (obj == 'true') {
                                $('#Like').val('');
                                $('#Dislike').val('');
                                alert("Data Saved Successfully");
                            }
                        },
                        error: function (result) {
                            alert("Error Occured, Try Again");
                        }
                    });
            }
        })
    });
</script>
```

Webmethod is shown below

```
[WebMethod] 
public static string UpdateDB(string like, string dislike) 
{ 
    //Add your stuff
}
```

take a look more details here [Call WebMethod from jquery in ASP.NET](http://codeanalyze.com/Articles/Details/20167/Update-database-from-jquery-javascript-in-aspnet-or-aspnet-mvc)